# How long do crushed grains last?

Tags: all-grain, grain

In a relatively short time period I will finally embark on all-grain brewing. I would rather purchase grains online as it is cheaper than the LHBS, but the LHBS won't let me use their crushing equipment unless I bought the grains from them.

I was hoping that there was some hard and fast rules regarding this, like "after 3 days, crushed grains start to lose potency; after 10 days, throw them out."

Does this time frame depend on the type of grain, or are they all about the same?

Is there any (relatively) non-anecdotal evidence in this regard? I.e. did anyone ever purchase 10 pounds of one grain, crush 5 pounds, and brewed n many days later? (Double blind taste tests preferred)

Comment: Remember that most local homebrew shops are not high-profit enterprises. Their prices may be bit higher, but you get the convenience of instant gratification when you need something for your brew. Support your LBHS! I buy grain by the sack from my LBHS to cut down on cost. You can buy your own mill and it will pay for itself over time.

Comment: I've drank so much free beer and gotten so much great advice at my local homebrew store (in addition to making some awesome friends) that it FAAARRR outweighs the cost savings of $.25/pound on malt or whatever from an online retailer.